# Remove duplicates from array comparing a specific key

Tags: php, arrays

Consider the same array but id of 3rd index is different:

```
$all_array = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [value] => 111
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [value] => 222
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [value] => 333
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [value] => 111
        )
)
```

Now, both 1 & 4 have same values. So we want to remove any of them:

```
$unique_arr = array_unique( array_column( $all_array , 'value' ) );
print_r( array_intersect_key( $all_array, $unique_arr ) );
```

Comment: Remove all array or just value ?

Comment: Do you want to remove both 1 & 4 or Just 1 or Just 4

Comment: When posting example data of arrays, please use `var_export($theArray)` and post the result of that. It will output the array in valid PHP syntax that we can use when testing/answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `foreach()` for it:

```
$finalArray = [];

foreach($all_array as $arr){
    
    $finalArray[$arr['value']] = $arr;
}

print_r($finalArray);
print_r(array_values($finalArray)); // to re-index array
```

https://3v4l.org/82XUI

Note: this code will give you always the last index data of the duplicate once

Answer (score 1):

Without `foreach` with `array_column`.

```
$array = array_column($all_array,null,'value');
$array = array_values($array);  //if the array is to be re-indexed

var_dump($array);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/CX8pK